# GNU compiler memory sanitizer is not available

Tags: c++, cmake, g++, memory-sanitizer

When I try to build my c++ project with memory sanitizer using the CMake sanitizers modules [here](https://github.com/arsenm/sanitizers-cmake), I get this warning:

> MemorySanitizer is not available for GNU compiler.

Although when I searched on google it is stated [here](https://hpc-wiki.info/hpc/Compiler_Sanitizers#MemorySanitizer) that GNU compiler supports memory sanitizer.

My development enviroment is WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 and compiler version is 9.4.0.

Comment: No, gcc does not support that sanitizer, you can check in the official doc...

Comment: But I am able to use address sanitizer. Moreover, I compiled and run the code [here](https://www.osc.edu/resources/getting_started/howto/howto_use_address_sanitizer) successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, [the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) does not document support for MemorySanitizer. There is no entry for `-fsanitize=memory`- but it has `-fsanitize=address`, `-fsanitize=leak`, `-fsanitize=thread` and several others.

[The High Performance Computing wiki page you linked in you question](https://hpc-wiki.info/hpc/Compiler_Sanitizers#MemorySanitizer) says:

> The C/C++ compilers Clang/LLVM and GCC support so-called sanitizers. These sanitizers are built into the application code and track the execution at runtime to report execution errors. There are currently four interesting sanitizers:
>
> - AddressSanitizer and LeakSanitizer
> - ThreadSanitizer
> - MemorySanitizer

So it looks like it is speaking in broad strokes and that those broad strokes are wrong specifically for GCC and MemorySantizer.

Cross reference: [Google wiki page on MSan](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/MemorySanitizer):

> MemorySanitizer is part of LLVM trunk and has been widely available as a compile-time option in clang since version 4.0.

Page for Clang support: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MemorySanitizer.html.

For your reference, the line of CMake code in the CMake helper modules you are using that prints that diagnostic message is here: https://github.com/arsenm/sanitizers-cmake/blob/77df84a2af66d35bec00205651cee7de6b2b2609/cmake/sanitize-helpers.cmake#L152.